# Could not build module and include of non-modular header inside framework module error in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7.3, swift2

I’m using Facebook login authentication in my application and used CocoaPods to add framework. Everything was fine until I upgraded to `Xcode7.3`.

Getting the following Error:

[image]

Pod Configuration:

```
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'
pod 'ParseTwitterUtils'
```

It suddenly showing the error when I open the project with `Xcode 7.3`.
Anyone knows what is causing the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Change the "Allow Non-modular includes in Framework Modules" to "Yes" in the Build Settings for your pod

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot. Actually I know this solution but the problem was, I was changing this setting in myproject's tab instead of 'Pods' tab. But I wonder why I'm getting this error in Xcode7.3 suddenly where there was no error in previous Xcode version. Anyway, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it removing `Modules` folder from the framework.

- Browse to your framework location which is present in the App Project using finder
- Go inside `Test.framework` folder (In the above case it will be `'FBSDKCorekit.framework`) & Delete `Modules` folder.
- Clean and Re Build the app, it will solve the problem.